# Products with different variants schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, nosql, schema

I am trying to create an e-commerce website using MongoDB. I have created a Product and variant model, my question is how can I search the product with variant, for example for "Size" user can add variant value as "S" or "Small". How can I search the product which has for example small product in this case as a product have many variants, how can I list eg. all products with small size. Here is my variant model.

```
var variantSchema = Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
count: {type: Number, default : 0}
});
```

And my Product Schema is:

```
var productSchema = Schema({
sku: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true
}, //, required: true, unique: true
name: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    max: 65,
    required: true
},
slug: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true,
    slug: "name",
    slug_padding_size: 3
},
status: Boolean,
listPrice: Number,
description: {
    short: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    long: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    }
},
images: [],
categoryId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category'
},
userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
isActive: Boolean,
vars: [
    {
        varId : {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Variants'
        },
        values: [
            {
                value : String,
                image:[]
            }
        ]
    }
]
});
```

Comment: Can you dump here some data? One from Product and one from Variant?

Comment: @HardikShah varianSchema only contain names for example: Size, color etc and in product vars contain varaint Id and values for example : varId:123 and values are whatever user add, he can enter "S" or "Small". My question is how i know that "S" and "Small" is same. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment.

You can distinguish "Small" and "small" by ignoring case sensitive.

```
UserModel.findOne({
    email: {'$regex': "^"+ email +"$", $options:'i'}
}, function (err, data) {
    callback(err, data)
});
```

But you can not match `S` with `Small`.

**Approach 1:**

You need to maintain the possible words that you want to consider as `Small`. Maybe by inserting in Variant Schema an array `["S", "Small"]` like this. But in this scenario. You must have to caution about `S`. `S` can be anything. **(I am not recommended this approach)**

**Approach 2:**

I would like to suggest making one schema (`SizeSchema`) that can present the size. for e.g. `Small, Large, Extra small, Extra Large etc...` And reference that `SizeSchema` to `VariantSchema` and `ProductSchema` to `VariantSchema`. (Triple relationship). And this would be fixed for the end user. No one will have an option like "S".

Hope this may help you.